# How to read specific attribute from external json file using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

How do I load external json file using d3 and select specific attribute from the file to be visualize. The code that I'm currently working at.

```
d3.json("assets/data/nr-coordinate.json", function(data) {
        var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

        overlay.onAdd = function() {
            var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append("div")
                    .attr("class", "students");

            overlay.draw = function() {
                var projection = this.getProjection(),
                        padding = 10;
                var marker = layer.selectAll("svg")
                        .data(d3.entries(data.students))  
                        .each(transform) 
                        .enter().append("svg:svg")
                        .each(transform)
                        .attr("class", "marker");

                marker.append("svg:circle")
                        .attr("r", 25)
                        .attr("cx", padding + 7)
                        .attr("cy", padding + 7);

                function transform(d) {
                    d = new google.maps.LatLng(d.value.coordinate[0], d.value.coordinate[1]);
                    d = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(d);
                    return d3.select(this)
                            .style("left", (d.x - padding) + "px")
                            .style("top", (d.y - padding) + "px");
                }
            };
        };
    overlay.setMap(map);
});
```

Sample data set

```
{
    "students": [
{ "sex": "M", "level":2, "faculty":"FSKM", "coordinate": [2.218773,102.4543398]},
...]}
```

When i try to append circle into the Google Map it didn't work out. I've set the zoomcontrol to true, but when i run that code, it's become totally static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading your external JSON incorrectly:

Instead of

```
d3.json("assets/data/nr-coordinate.json", function(data) {
```

correct way:

```
d3.json("assets/data/nr-coordinate.json", function(error, data) {
```

That's the reason why its not working.

Refer [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests)

Comment: thank you :) do you know to select specific attribute? lets say sex, because i want to do some selection in there of what attribute to display

Comment: yeah you can do something like `data.students.map(function(a){ return a.sex})` will return you an array of sex values in students.

Comment: @Cyril If we wanted to parse a JSON file uploaded by the user then what modifications are required to the above code??

Comment: Its already parsed into object stored in data.. you don't have to to do anything special.

Comment: @Cyril can you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36196895/alternate-color-of-circle-based-on-data-set-attribute-value? not sure how to do it right way